# Needed for the Date and Time return formula in Excel

Tags: google-sheets

This is the code to return time for getting the first message text in column C61.

```
=if(ISTEXT(C61),TEXT(NOW(),"hh:mm"),"00:00")
```

This is the code to return time for last message in column E61.

```
=if(ISTEXT(E61),TEXT(NOW(),"hh:mm"),"00:00")
```

This code works fine to return time, But when the last message is entered in column E61 the time at column B61 also gets changed. I don't understand why this is happening, because there is no relation of these two columns to each other. They have to change the times on column B61 and D61.
But they both are grabbing the same time from the system.

[image]

Comment: `NOW()` is volatile, which means it will recalc every time there is a change in the workbook.  If you want to make it static you will need to code it and not use formula.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sorry to bother you, Can you provide an example like how I can make it static. I tried coding it for static using conditions, but I was not able to come up with any.

Comment: You will need to use Google app script.  This cannot be done with formula or conditional formatting. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible to solve with formulae. you need a script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() =="Sheet1" ) {                   //sheet
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 5 ) {                       //monitor column E
  var nextCell = r.offset(0, -1);                //print timestamp in column D
  var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
  "GMT+8", "HH:mm");                             //format of the timestamp and timezone
  nextCell.setValue(newDate);
}}}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71815326/5632629